# Delete "Project SDK" configuration in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, version

Here is a screenshot of [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) 2017.3.3 "New Project" dialog box.

[image: screenshot of IntelliJ 2017.3.3 "New Project" dialog box]

Note how the `Project SDK` popup shows in red text an older release of Java 9 that I physically deleted from my Mac (from the `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines folder`).

⇒ How do I delete that particular "Project SDK" setting within IntelliJ?

Clicking the "New" button in the upper-right of that dialog lets me *add* another JVM but does not allow me to *delete*.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

- Select **Project Structure** from the **File** menu.
- Click **SDKs** in the left column and select the SDK you want to remove.
- Click the **Delete** icon (the minus sign).
- Click **Apply** (essential!) then **OK** to close the **Project Structure** window.

I just tried this in 2017.3.3 and it worked fine. The [JetBrains documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdks-java.html) states that you can also click **Alt+DELETE** instead of clicking the **Delete** icon, but that didn't work for me.

Here's the screen:

[image: deleteSDK]

To be clear, this action means that the SDK you just removed will no longer be available when you try to create a new project; that SDK will have to be added again on an individual project basis if needed.

Comment: So you go through a *project-specific* settings dialog to set an *IDE-wide* "platform" setting?! How bizarre. IntelliJ is so slick in some regards, and so poorly-designed in others.

Comment: @BasilBourque Well not quite...you do it through the _generic_ project settings screen rather than a _project-specific_ screen (as shown in the OP). But I agree that it's not intuitive, and the SDK settings really belong under **File->Settings**.

Comment: @BasilBourque Pls ignore my previous comment - you were 100% correct, and there is no such thing as a generic project settings screen. (It's late.)